# How can I have the same javascript variable on the same page?

Tags: javascript, variables, embed

Our service offers the ability to drop in some javascript on your page and display some tracking data, but I'd like for customers to be able to embed multiple instances of the embed code on the same page.

The problem right now is that I can't include the same variables names on the page.

For instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ttp_number = "1Z8E26R80281495993"; // Tracking number

  var ttp_key="123456";
  (function(){
    document.write('<div id="ttp"></div>');
    s=document.createElement('script');
    s.type="text/javascript";
    s.src="http://c.trackthepack.com/j/e?" + Math.random();
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('ttp').appendChild(s);",1);
  })()
</script>
```

Then if they wanted to be able to embed that again, I'd have to change all variable names:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ttp_number_001 = "446888240962"; // Tracking number

  var ttp_key_001="123456";
  (function(){
    document.write('<div id="ttp_001"></div>');
    s_001=document.createElement('script');
    s_001.type="text/javascript";
    s_001.src="http://c.trackthepack.com/j/e?" + Math.random();
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('ttp_001').appendChild(s_001);",1);
  })()
</script>
```

I'm okay with having them change the contents of the `function()` block, but the `ttp_number` and `ttp_key` need to stay the same variable name.

Right now, when I have multiple embeds on the page, they all inherit the contents of the variables in the last embed code.

So, the ultimate question here...how do I fix that?

Comment: Why `setTimeout`? Without it you'd have blocking semantics and what you want would work as expected.

Comment: The idea is that embedding the code this way keeps it from slowing down page loads if our server is down/slow/whatever.

Comment: How and where are the `ttp_number` and `ttp_key` variables being utilized? EDIT: Nevermind, I see them in the script that is being returned.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe store the ttp_key and ttp_number's in arrays instead?

Comment: Well I guess I wonder how Google Adsense does it. I mean you could embed a dozen things on the same page and they don't interfere, but they've got their customizable variables set up similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not declare the variables in the function body. Then they're only scoped to that function. You can still set them to different values when you dump the script into the HTML.

I know you mention/imply that the user can edit the function (for some reason) but that just seems like a world of hurt to me, so I'm hoping that that's not actually the case.

Comment: The variables will go out of scope when the function ends, and the script file will not have access to them due to the OPs usage of `setTimeout` to inject the script.

Comment: Roatin, I don't think setTimeout is the issue here. I've removed that in testing and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Shpigford: you know what you are right. I just realized the DOM method you are using to inject the script (`.appendChild(...)`) will cause the scripts to load asynchronously, regardless of `setTimeout`. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you cachebusting with `Math.random()`? Does the JavaScript at `http://c.trackthepack.com/j/e` change often? If not, you should let the cache do its job.

But if so, could you make it dynamic enough to inspect the arguments it's called with and use those arguments directly, instead of relaying them via the global `window` object, so that you load `http://c.trackthepack.com/j/e?n=446888240962&k=123456` and it doesn't have to look them up when the script runs?